# Get RSS link from page into RSSDemon

Tags: rss

When I tap on an explicit RSS link shown in a web page, I have the opportunity to complete the action using RSSDemon. But no such thing happens for hidden RSS links, whose presence is revealed via the RSS icon in the address bar. When I tap on that, I can only add the feed to Google reader. Then I have to import the link from Google reader. How can this be bypassed? I want to go straight to my preferred RSS app.

Comment: Maybe you can use catch-all handlers like [Copy to clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.johanhil.clipboard) or [Andmade Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share) (replaces stock share target menu and adds multi sharing, e.g. to send a file via BT and GDrive in one step). Let me know if it works!